# Seam. Log in using Email or Username

Tags: email, authentication, seam

I'm trying to provide the user with the capability of "loging in" using either her/his username or her/his email. The thing is that afaik, I can have only one @UserPrincipal into my User class. 
Any idea of how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define the Emailadress as unique in the User table.

When the user enters an emailaddress, lookup the Username from the table and use it to authenticate.

Comment: Yes, this is what I did! it was easier than I thought. Thanks anyway!